# How do you log all an element's properties?

Tags: javascript

I want to see in the console all the available properties on an html element.

```
console.log(myEl);
```

Just logs the html structure of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://getfirebug.com/logging: console.dir(object)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "";
for ( var attr in myEl )
{
  if (typeof myEl[attr]!="function")
    str += attr + ":" + myEl[attr] + "\n";
}
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
for (var key in a)
    console.log(key, a[key]);
```